# How to handle distance in postgis using ST_DWithin

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm super new with this subject and was assigned the task of creating a query to find objects around a given point using some type of radius search using Postgresql with PostGis. After some research I came across the `ST_DWithin` method which is perfect for this.

I'm currently having some issues with the query. Here is how it looks like:

`SELECT * FROM waypoints WHERE ST_DWithin(lonlat, '002000000100000f11c05e9335158b82804047dcae85b9e8c4', 10)`

This is a table that stores `lonlat` using SRID=3857 and I'm creating the second geometry using  `FACTORY.point(circle.fetch('lon'), circle.fetch('lat'))` from [Ruby RGEO](https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo)

Now the [documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) states that if I'm using geometries then the third parameter `distance_of_srid` should be in the units of the geometries.

The problem is that both `lonlat` and the point are using SRID 3857 which from what I understood correctly, uses units in meters. Logically I would expect that `distance_of_srid` would accept distances in meters. But when I send the query I get waypoints that are kilometers away not 10 meter away. But if I break it down to say .01 then it brings waypoints that are within 10 meters or at least that's what it seems.

I feel like I'm lacking some knowledge to overcome this but not sure what it is or where is a good place to get more acquainted with this subject. If someone could help me with this issue or point me to a better direction that would be awesome!

**Update:**

Based on a comment below I tried doing the following:

```
ST_DWithin(ST_Transform(archived_listings.lonlat, 4326)::geography, ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-122.300115 47.724076)'), 10000.0)
```

But unfortunately I'm getting nothing with 10 km as before I was getting a house that was closer than that.

Comment: The geometry you are using is not in EPSG:3857, it's pretty clearly in EPSG:4326. select st_astext('002000000100000f11c05e9335158b82804047dcae85b9e8c4')

Comment: @PaulRamsey Thanks for the quick reply! How did you know its EPSG:4326, when I run the query I just get "POINT(-122.300115 47.724076)". Also when I create the `Factory` I use `Geo::Geos::CAPIFactory.create(srid: 3857)`

Comment: that is lat/lon because if it was in metres it would be on Null Island

Comment: @IanTurton couldn't get what you meant by your comment. Can you please elucidate?

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some further debugging and taking into account the comments in the question. I realized that the data stored in the `lanlot` column was actually `SRID=4326` even do the column states that it's a `SRID=3857` geometry.

I came to this conclusion because when I plugged the coordinates as a 3857 in a [map](https://epsg.io/map#srs=3857&x=-122.300045&y=47.723779&z=2) I was placed very close to the [null island](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island). But when I put the same coordinates as 4326 I was place in the [correct location](https://epsg.io/map#srs=4326&x=-122.519531&y=47.159840&z=2).

Since we already had over 1 million entries on the production database there was no time to change the column so the query ended up been something like:

```
SELECT * FROM waypoints 
WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_SetSRID(lonlat, 4326)::geography, 
                 ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-122.300045 47.723779)', 4326)::geography, 
                 10)
```

And it works!!